# Are there ways to mirror submodules in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, mirror

I mirrored repo with submodule from one Gitlab to another. I used Gitlab settings to create mirror. But the problem is - the submodule in mirrored repo stayed the same like in `.gitmodules`.

I want my mirrored repo to use a mirror of submodule. Are there easy ways to do it with Gitlab repo mirror? For instance, set conditions in `.gitmodules` or any settings. Thanks.